# Tool for creating a JAXB java class out of xml schema (reverse schemagen)?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

How to create a JAXB java class out of a xml schema using a utility?
I don't like reverse-engineering of several huge XSD-files to a JAXB-compliant java class.

I know there's the jdk utility schemagen - but this works the other way round.
What tool can help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the command line `xjc` tool or the ant task version:

http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxb/xjc.html

Answer (score 4):

You want the `xjc` tool. It sits alongside `schemagen` in the JDK, and generates JAXB-annotated java from an XML Schema. See official JavaSE docs [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html).